# How to parse UTF-16 XML received from API call

Tags: php, arrays, xml, curl, utf-16

I am making an API call using PHP CURL to a specific URL. I am able to receive response in my browser.

CURL is saving this response in a Variable like this:

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now when I use

```
print_r(htmlspecialchars($output, true));
```

I get this response in my browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<loginres>
<sessiontoken>123456</sessiontoken>
<timeout>7/30/2016 11:18:22 AM</timeout>
<status>1</status>
</loginres>
```

Since, this is a UTF-16 encoded response, I am not able to use SimpleXML or DOM document. You can try this out(I have failed several times). Nothing is coming.

Also, I have tried, to use "explode" function with Array filter, and the response looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] =>  version="1.0"
[2] => encoding="utf-16"
[3] => standalone="no"?>


[5] => 123456

[7] => 7/30/2016
[8] => 11:26:09
[9] => AM

[11] => 1

)
```

Now, my question is , how do I use this file....
I wanted to create PHP variables out of XML tags, and parse them, to manipulate and save in my database.

The other option is to save the response in an xml file, in my local server, and use it using Jquery, Ajax, but I don't know how to do it. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If properly defined DOM will load UTF-16 just fine. The API will still return UTF-8.

```
// create some xml string and convert it to utf-16
$xml = iconv('utf-8', 'utf-16', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><foo>Ä</foo>');

// look an encoded special char and a BOM
var_dump($xml);

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);

// loaded just fine, here is the node content as UTF-8
var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
```

Output https://eval.in/614245:

```
string(104) "��<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><foo>�</foo>"
string(2) "Ä"
```

Comment: The purpose of my question was to seek help on how to use an UTF-16 xml produced by API response, in PHP. I wanted to create variables from the XML Tags, and do manipulation. Converting it on the DOM itself will be tough, as I do not have control over the API server.

Comment: Here is no difference - fetch it using file_get_contents() and load it into the DOM. If it is not broken DOM will load it.